# How can I avoid range index error for fields with the same name as the index field in attached documents?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf

For my project I have to ingress and curate data from various sources.
I do that through the data-hub framework using flows.
All my different sources have a field called "date". However they all come in different forms e.g. yyyy-mm-dd, yyyymmdd, dd.mm.yyyy.

I do the curation through a mapping step to one common format yyyy-mm-dd.
After the mapping the field is still called "date".

Since I want to be able to do range searches I need an index on my "date". However this leads to error when ingesting the data as the ingested data's "date" field is not yet mapped to the right format.

My solution was to not reject invalid values for the STAGING database. However because the old document is attached in the envelope of the curated new document that is moved to the FINAL database after the mapping I get a range index error for the attached document.

I want to reject invalid values in the FINAL database but I also want to keep the original document as an attachment in the final file.

The only solution I can see so far is to name the "date" element in the FINAL database something like iDate in order to avoid conflicts.

This doesn't seem like a clean solution to me. Do you have better suggestions?

I am using:

- centos 7
- Marklogic 10
- Marklogic data-hub 5.2.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a path range index, you can limit it to just those `date` elements that are in the top-level instance and not in the attachment.

See https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/range_index#id_40666 for details on using path range indexes.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for the quick response. However I find it a bit missleading in Quickstart that when you click the range index symbol in the entity (little lightning symbol) an element range index is createt which targets all such. elements in the database.

Comment: Of yourse if you used cts to query before, after changing the index to a path range index you have to use a cts.pathRangeQuery

Comment: This is a valid comment and would make sense for you to provide this feedback to the Data Hub development team with an issue: https://github.com/marklogic/marklogic-data-hub. That said, you probably want to think a bit about the names of your fields in your entities. What is the meaning of the 'date' field? Is it a birth date? Is it an order date? etc. Give the properties in your entities names that mean something from the business perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Configure a path field to target only the normalized dates, excluding those original date elements that are in the envelope.

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/fields#id_23934

> In a path field, the included and excluded elements are constrained to the sub-tree identified by the path. For example, if the path for the field is /A/B/C, only elements in node C, such as A/B/C/D, A/B/C/D/E and /A/B/C/Z, are included or excluded from the field.

> A path field may include one or more paths. Multiple paths are treated as the union of the paths. Consequently, each of them will identify a root of a field-instance in a given document.

Answer (score 0):

Giving your standardized "date" element a different name seems like a perfectly clean approach. Ideally, all elements of the same name (qualified by namespace) have the same definition and the same semantics. When your sources give you "dates" that are not actually xs:dates, then the "date" node being provided is really just a (slightly constrained) string. Sure, it describes a date in some easily-translated way, but it's not actually a date field, and so it's not indexable as a date field. When you standardize your source data, you're creating a new data point, one which actually is a date, and it 'should' take a new identity: either a new local name as you suggest, or "date" in your "normalized data" namespace.

```
<envelope>
  <original>
    <date>09-09-2020</date>
    <!-- etc -->
  </original>
  <normalized>
    <my:date>2020-09-09</my:date>
  </normalized>
</envelope>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However I am using JSON data where I cannot use namespaces. Then it can always be the case that some data I ingest has the exact same name as my newly defined field in the normalized data.